# Python - Open browser with click

Tags: python

I am currently uploading a file and opening it's content on a website with

```
click.launch('http://example.com/fileThatIUploaded.php')
```

I want to delete the file once the user closes the browser window though.

Can someone please help with how this trigger is utilized?

I'm using [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) module.

Comment: Here you go: [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove)

Comment: Can you confirm you are using selenium to drive a browser? Does your program run on the same host as the web server process?

Comment: The program does run on the same host where the browser window is opened. This particular functionality just opens the browser with the uploaded file, and once the user (manually) exits the browser, I need to remove the file.

Kevin, I am aware how to remove a file, however I want to do this specifically once the user closes the browser window, not before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the docs:

http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#click.launch

click.launch() accepts a "wait" argument. Therefore, you could do

click.launch('http://example.com/fileThatIUploaded.php', wait=True)

And delete the file when it returns. If you need to do other stuff while it's happening, do this in a thread.